# How to give dynamic height if div added dynamically as per below reference image only by CSS?

Tags: html, css

[image: dynamic elements condition]

How to give dynamic height if div added dynamically as per below reference image? I want all div to fit in window height. **I want to achieve it only by CSS**

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `flexbox` in *column* `flex-direction` and give `flex: 1` to the *flex children* - see demo below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
section {
  display: inline-flex;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

section > div {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>

<section>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Appreciate your quick response. I want to achieve as same as this link https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/Jeryz 

Is there any way to achieve it without using flex? and by using calc function in CSS?